# hiding file upload button

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm having troubles hiding an option. It works like this: when I find an archive with an 'R' type, I have to hide the related button. So what I did was put the button in a div with id "`hayResolucion`", so once I find an 'R' type archive, I just hide it. Here is the code:

```
<div id="hayResolucion" name="hayResolucion">
    <td colspan="3" align="left" valign="middle" class="sangrar">Archivo Resolución:
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000"/>
        <input type="file" name="archivo_r"/>
    </td>
</div>
```

and here is the function that it's supposed to hide it:

```
<?php if($row_archivos['tipo']=='R'){ ?>
  <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#hayResolucion").hide();
      });
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Why you don't hide it before HTML generation ? If the solution is build by PHP it can be directly set on the HTML instead adding JS to hide HTML..

Comment: Because if I hide it before HTML, then how will i show it in case i need it? It would be the same problem, but instead of hiding it, i'd have to show it otherwise

Comment: But if you check is INSIDE you PHP logic as it is, then there is no difference when you will check it, the result will be the same.. And in that case why you don't check that at your HTML creation ?

Comment: Because that's what i do, I check it while i generate it with PHP. The "if(){ <script></script> }" is inside the generation.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of making:

```
<?php if($row_archivos['tipo']=='R'){ ?>
  <script>
```

Can you add this check at the HTML generation..

```
<?php if($row_archivos['tipo']!='R'){ ?>
  <div id="hayResolucion" name="hayResolucion">
```

or even with inline check.

```
<div id="hayResolucion"
    <?=$row_archivos['tipo']=='R'?'style="display:none;"':''?> name="hayResolucion">
```

There is no point to generate both HTML and JS with PHP and after its finished the JS to hide the HTML..

Comment: That is because the JS has to be made after HTML because the page has the button before showing the uploaded archives, that's why i'm usig DIVs with IDs to hide

Comment: Does your PHP generates the HTML ? And if so why you don't make that check while you generate it instead of making a JS fix..

Comment: Yes, my PHP generates the HTML, and i check it while i generate it. Actually, the "if(){ <script></script> }" is inside the generation.

Comment: Ok, in that case you know at the time of HTML generation do you need it.. 
And so.. why you have to print it and after that to add JS which will delete it? Instead of just skipping it or if you need it to exists as HTML just put display:none style..

Comment: Because there is only one button that adds the archives, and it was created long before the archives are shown. I don't need to skip the archives, I just need to hide it whenever I find an 'R' type archive, so I can't skip the button so far. But the display:none style got my attention..is there any way I can use it to hide the button after I created it? I'm not familiar with display:none, could you teach me how to use it?

Comment: You have to rethink your Logic.. its broken! 
PHP check $row_archivos['tipo']=='R' run on server before it outputs your HTML.. It knows that this archivos is not for a button and you don't display it.
Now if you have ANY JS based code which needs to hide/show the button dynamic this is other material..

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me, you just need to wrap it up inside document.ready func

```
<?php if($row_archivos['tipo']=='R'){ ?>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).find('#hayResolucion').hide();
   });
  </script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I thought it could be the document.ready func, but it wasn't just that, so i edited the question

Comment: @W.Tonki add an else condition and put an alert there to verify the issue.

Comment: @W.Tonki  That's weird, are you having multiple hayResolucion id's?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should make sure the DOM is loaded

```
<?php if($row_archivos['tipo']=='R') : ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#hayResolucion').hide();
});
</script>
<?php endif;
```

Comment: are you sure `$row_archivos['tipo']` equals `R`?